fslightbox: Disable buttons on first and last gallery item
I just implemented fslightbox into my HTML. I want to disable the previous button on the frist item of the gallery and the next button on the last item.
I have no idea how to do this. Has anyone of your some experience with this plugin?
As I have nearly no experience with JS, I asked ChatGPT, but its answer did not work.
<script>
  const lightbox = new FsLightbox();

  lightbox.props.beforeShow = (slide, props) => {
    if (slide === 0) {
      // Hide the previous button on the first image
      props.ui.prevButton.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      // Show the previous button on other slides
      props.ui.prevButton.style.display = '';
    }

    if (slide === props.sources.length - 1) {
      // Hide the next button on the last image
      props.ui.nextButton.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      // Show the next button on other slides
      props.ui.nextButton.style.display = '';
    }
  };
</script>

